# Get the total count of True and False at groupby level and total count of True only, False only and Combination of True-False from the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A",20,True],["C",21,True],["B",20,False],["A",21,False],["B",20,False],["A",20,False]],columns=["id1","id2","val1"])
```

```
id1 id2 val1
A   20  True
C   21  True
B   20  False
A   21  False
B   20  False
A   20  False
```

I need total count of True and False at id1 and id2 groupby level.

**Expected Output1**

```
df_out1 = pd.DataFrame([["A",20,1,1],["A",21,0,1],["B",20,0,2],["C",21,1,0]],columns=["id1","id2","Total_True","Total_False"])
```

```
id1 id2 Total_True  Total_False
A   20     1             1
A   21     0             1
B   20     0             2
C   21     1             0
```

Also I need another output which tells how many id1 and id2 combination has All the True values, How many has all the False Values and how many id1 and id2 combination have both True and False values.

**Expected Output2**

```
df_out2 = pd.DataFrame([["All_True",1],["All_False",2],["Both_TrueFalse",1]],columns=["Type","Total_id"])
```

```
Type           Total_id
All_True           1
All_False          2
Both_TrueFalse     1
```

How to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1: Calculate frequency table

```
s = pd.crosstab([df['id1'], df['id2']], df['val1'])

# val1     False  True 
# id1 id2              
# A   20       1      1
#     21       1      0
# B   20       2      0
# C   21       0      1
```

Part 2: Use boolean algebra to count the values that satisfy the given conditions

```
m1, m2 = s[True].astype(bool), s[False].astype(bool)
pd.Series({'All_True': sum(m1 & ~m2), 'All_False': sum(~m1 & m2), 'Both': sum(m1 & m2)})


# All_True     1
# All_False    2
# Both         1
# dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't need the first output (a `crosstab`), you can get the final one directly by computing the mean per id ([`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html)), all True will give you 1, all False give 0 and any combination will be in between:

```
(df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'])['val1'].mean()
   .map({1: 'All_True', 0: 'All_False'})
   .fillna('Both_TrueFalse').value_counts()
)
```

Output:

```
All_False         2
Both_TrueFalse    1
All_True          1
Name: val1, dtype: int64
```